# Docker failed to initialize

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am trying to install the Docker community edition for windows, the installation was successful and it asked me to logout and login again and I did same. But when I tried to start the docker it says -

> A task was canceled.
>   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters)
>      at Docker.WPF.BackendClient.Version()
>      at Docker.Program.Run(IReadOnlyCollection`1 args)

It is giving me below options -

[image: Docker Error]

Any help or pointers will really helpful.

Comment: It looks like a problem with Hyper-V. https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24672#issuecomment-238685957 may be help you.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Just need to delete the files in C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Docker fixed it

Comment: Thanks!!! that worked for me. When I checked the log files in the logs folder, I had logs from 2020. It was probably from an old installation that I removed a year ago.

Comment: Deleting only %APPDATA%\Docker\settings.json helped, thanks.

Comment: Got the same error after updating docker. This resolved it.

Answer (score 22):

Deleting `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Docker` folder also resolved my issue.

Answer (score 19):

Just Remove all files under this paths:

```
C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Local\Docker
C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Docker
C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Docker Desktop
```

Once deleted, I didn’t have to do anything else, Docker Desktop started booting up as normal.

Answer (score 8):

I did finally solve the problem and the solution was to restart the machine, which was not properly documented in the official site. As per the site -

> Install

> Double-click InstallDocker.msi to run the installer.

> When the installation finishes, Docker starts automatically. The whale in the notification area indicates that Docker is running, and accessible from a terminal.
> Run

> Open a command-line terminal like PowerShell, and try out some Docker commands!

> Run docker version to check the version.

> Run docker run hello-world to verify that Docker can pull and run images.

However it needs a restart to enable virtualization, simply logging off and login again did not work for me as directed by the wizard. Most of the problems related to docker gets resolved by restarting the docker some of the common problems and the resolutions are as follows

- Docker not starting in windows or not working properly

  - Change it to Linux containers
- Make sure that docker is installed on machine
- Make sure virtualization is enabled and docker starts successfully

Comment: I restarted my machine _twice_, after that it worked :-)

Answer (score 4):

Proxy was the culprit in my case:

In the log file in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Docker`,

[11:43:09.152][GoBackendProcess ][Error ] msg=“while parsing JSON from C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json: json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field Content.proxyHttpMode of type string”

Open `%APPDATA%\Docker\settings.json`

I **removed all settings lines related to proxy**, and the service started fine.

Alternatively, you can delete the following directories:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Docker
%APPDATA%\Docker
%APPDATA%\Docker Desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issues generated by the following error described in the `C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Docker\log.txt`:

```
[12:35:12.988][GUI               ][Warning] Failed to configure docker scan: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: O acesso ao caminho 'C:\Users\<myuser>\.docker\scan\config.json' foi negado.
   em System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
```

To solve that I just dropped the folder located at `C:\Users\<myuser>\.docker` and run the Docker Desktop again.

Answer (score 1):

i didn't find correct solutions here, even though it's the first page of google, just do the following:

1. Go to C:\Users%user%\AppData\Roaming\Docker
2. Delete file locked-directories

Profit!

Hope this helps a lot.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue recently (10-10-2023). To fix this issue, open this folder: `C:\Users\{Your-machine-User-Name}\AppData\Roaming\Docker`, where you can find the `settings.json` file, Delete that file and restart your PC. This method work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled/installed docker and that solved all the issues

Answer (score 0):

Just remove:
C:\Users%user%\AppData\Roaming\Docker\locked-directories
C:\Users%user%\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json

then restart your machine, which would solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Tried all sort of things but just restarting my pc did the trick

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).