# Docker Desktop cannot start the docker daemon on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-desktop

I’m currently having a problem when trying to use Docker on Windows.

Before the last update, I could use Docker normally, and the Docker deamon started automatically on startup.

I start Docker by opening the Docker Desktop, I can see it is starting, but it just hangs there for a while, before it stops automatically, showing the following error message:

```
Cancellation token triggered before we finished reading from the stream.
   à HttpOverStream.ByLineReader.<ReadLineAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à HttpOverStream.Client.DialMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Docker.Core.Logging.LoggingMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext() dans C:\workspaces\master\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Logging\LoggingMessageHandler.cs:ligne 30
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Docker.Core.BackendAPI.BackendAPIClient.<CreateHyperVVMAsync>d__10.MoveNext() dans C:\workspaces\master\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\BackendAPI\BackendAPIClient.cs:ligne 92
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Docker.Engines.LinuxHyperVEngine.<DoStartAsync>d__14.MoveNext() dans C:\workspaces\master\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\LinuxHyperVEngine.cs:ligne 59
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() dans C:\workspaces\master\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:ligne 20
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() dans C:\workspaces\master\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:ligne 29
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() dans C:\workspaces\master\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:ligne 74
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.<StartAsync>d__14.MoveNext() dans C:\workspaces\master\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:ligne 69
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Docker.Engines.Engines.<RestartAsync>d__28.MoveNext() dans C:\workspaces\master\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\Engines.cs:ligne 272
```

- Docker version: 19.03.13-beta2, build ff3fbc9d55
- Docker desktop version 2.3.0.4 (46911)
- Windows version: Windows 10 Professional 1809

I have tried uninstalling and updating Docker, but it does not work.

Hyper-V is enabled and I have also enabled the Virtualisation Technology in BIOS.

Comment: you could try using an older non-beta version of docker. this could be achieved by using chocolatey on Windows

Comment: I have already tried to install some non-beta versions of docker. However, I am facing the same issue. I am starting to think that is the company antivirus, Symantec Endpoint Protection, that is blocking the starting of the docker daemon.

Comment: @Alex Blasco were you able to fix this issue ?? Running into same thing now

Comment: @DonWoodward I had to use another brand new company laptop in order to have a clean installation, it is just a brute force solution. Sorry to do not be able to provide better approach

Answer (score 1):

[image: docker desktop troubleshoot]

Open the Docker Desktop Dashboard and follow these steps:

1. Open the `Troubleshoot` page
2. Click on the `Clean / Purge data` button
3. Check the `Hyper-V` option
4. Click on `Delete`

This error happens because a Hyper-V virtual disk is created.

I use Docker Desktop v3.3.1 and this worked for me.

Comment: So, to the problem being "I cannot open Docker" your solution is "to open Docker..."??

Answer (score 0):

In my case the docker config file, located at: `%USERPROFILE%\.docker\config.json`, was in read-only mode.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941210/docker-failed-to-initialize)

Refer this link to see the working solution to this problem.
Basically you need to delete this file:
**C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Docker**

fixed it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).