# Docker failed to initialize, Docker Desktop is shutting down win10 Home

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4XFs.jpg)I got an error Docker failed to initialize, Docker Desktop is shutting down.
I uninstalled then restart my computer then I reinstalled again with admin. But couldnt solve this error. I used Windows 10 Home Single Language
How can I solve this error? (I attached screenshot)
Thanks

Comment: have u installed the prerequisites? hyperv or windows sub system for linux ? Could share the screenshot of the error.

Comment: Check these steps to install [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)

Comment: Hi I installed wsl --install in powershell. Restarted my computer than again same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker failed to initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941210/docker-failed-to-initialize)

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 home, hiperv(hypervisor) to available(but you can also enable it). so you have to use wsl, so follow this guide on [how to install docker desktop with wsl](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/).

if you followed the guide, please check,

- Windows subsystem for Linux
- Virtual Machine Platform

are enabled in Windows features, check [this guide](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7247-turn-windows-features-off-windows-10-a.html) if you don't know how to enable them.